# Mapbox GL and .net core webApi

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, mapbox-gl-js

I am moving from Leaflet to Mapbox GL and have some data issues. My webApi is proven but I cannot smoothly integrate them.

The approach I gave up on, based upon their examples and my own research, looks like:

```
        map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'mapdiv',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
            , center: start
            , zoom: $scope.zoom
            , transformRequest: (url, resourceType) => {
                if (resourceType === 'Source' && url.startsWith(CONFIG.API_URL)) {
                    return {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorageService.get("authorizationData")
                            , 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': CONFIG.APP_URL
                            , 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This is passing my OAuth2 token (or at least I think it should be) and the Cross site scripting part CORS.

Accompanying the above with:

```
map.addSource(layerName, { type: 'geojson', url: getLayerURL($scope.remLayers[i]) });
map.getSource(layerName).setData(getLayerURL($scope.remLayers[i]));
```

Having also tried to no avail:

```
map.addSource(layerName, { "type": 'geojson', "data": { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [] }});
map.getSource(layerName).setData(getLayerURL($scope.remLayers[i]));
```

Although there are no errors Fiddler does not show any requests being made to my layer webApi. All the others show but Mapbox does not appear to raising them.

The Url looks like:
http://localhost:49198/api/layer/?bbox=36.686654090881355,34.72821077223763,36.74072742462159,34.73664000652042&dtype=l&id=cf0e1df7-9510-4d03-9319-d4a1a7d6646d&sessionId=9a7d7daf-76fc-4dd8-af4f-b55d341e60e4

Because this was not working I attempted to make it more manual using my existing $http calls which partially works.

```
map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'mapdiv',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
            , center: start
            , zoom: $scope.zoom
            , transformRequest: (url, resourceType) => {
                if (resourceType === 'Source' && url.startsWith(CONFIG.API_URL)) {
                    return {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorageService.get("authorizationData")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

               map.addSource(layerName,
                    {
                        "type": 'geojson',
                        "data": { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [] }
                    });
```

The tricky part is to know when to run the data retrieval call. The only place I could find was on the maps data event which now looks like:

```
map.on('data', function (e) {
            if (e.dataType === 'source' && e.isSourceLoaded === false && e.tile === undefined) {
                // See if the datasource is known
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.remLayers.length; i++) {
                    if (e.sourceId === $scope.remLayers[i].name) {
                        askForData(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    function askForData(i) {
        var data = getBBoxString(map);
        var mapZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
        if (checkZoom(mapZoomLevel, $scope.remLayers[i].minZoom, $scope.remLayers[i].maxZoom)) {
            mapWebSvr.getData({
                bbox: data, dtype: 0, id: $scope.remLayers[i].id, buffer: $scope.remLayers[i].isBuffer, sessionId
            },  
                function (data, indexValue, indexType) {
                    showNewData(data, indexValue, indexType);
                },
                function () {
                    // Not done yet.
                },
                i,
                0
            );
        }
}

    function showNewData(ajxresponse, index, indexType) {
        map.getSource($scope.remLayers[index].name).setData(ajxresponse);
        map.getSource($scope.remLayers[index].name).isSourceLoaded = true;
    }
```

This is all working with one exception. It keeps firing time and time again. Some of these calls return a lot of data for a web call so its not a solution at the moment.
Its like its never satisfied with the data even though its showing it on the map!
There is a parameter on the data event, isSourceLoaded but it does not get set to true.
I have searched for an example, have tried setting isSourceLoaded in a number of places (as with the code above) but to no avail.

Does anyone have a method accomplishing this basic data retrieval function successfully or can point out the error(s) in my code? Or even point me to a working example...

I have spent too long on this now and could do with some help.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of a run around I have a solution.
A Mapbox email pointed to populating the data in the load event - which I am now doing.
This was not however the solution I was looking for as the data needs refreshing when the map moves, zooms etc - further look ups are required. 
Following a bit more a examination a solution was found. 
Using the code blow on the render event will request the information when the bounding box is changed.

```
        var renderStaticBounds = getBoundsString(map.getBounds());
        map.on('render', function (e) {
            if (renderStaticBounds != getBoundsString(map.getBounds())) {
                renderStaticBounds = getBoundsString(map.getBounds());
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.remLayers.length; i++) {
                    askForData(i);
                }
            }
        });
        function getBoundsString(mapBounds) {
            var left = mapBounds._sw.lng;
            var bottom = mapBounds._sw.lat;
            var right = mapBounds._ne.lng;
            var top = mapBounds._ne.lat;
            return left + ',' + bottom + ',' + right + ',' + top;
        }
```

This hopefully will save someone some development time.